# write the following complex numbers in the form a+bi

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to write the following complex numbers in the form *a+bi*, where *a* and *b* are real numbers and *i*=√*I*

(3-4i)+(1+ √1)

(2 + 2i)(2 - 3i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x = (3+4i) + (1+\sqrt{-1}) = 3+1+4i + i = 4+5i\,,$$
assuming the convention $\sqrt{-1}=i$.

$$y=(2+2i)(2-3i) = 4+4i-6i-6i^2=10-2i\,.$$